# Windows Server 2012 R2 update stuck after restart at 9%

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I installed windows server 2012 R2 on a server with IIS, SQL, TFS and some other Microsoft products. After finished installation, I ran windows update which asked for restart to continue installation.

After restart, update continues till 9% then it stops for ever!!!

I failed to start it also with safe mode or last good know configuration mode!

I don't have a recovery image CD for my installation.

What should I do? how can I either fix the issue or cancel the installation?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to access **cmd** from troubleshooting or SafeMode console, then run the following command:

`dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions`

Answer (score 4):

The below text is copied from https://www.craythorne.co.za/server-2012-stuck-at-updating-your-system-8/:

---

> **The Scenario:**
>
> One of my Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard servers installed a large
>   number of updates +200 all at once (so unfortunately I’ve no idea
>   which one caused this problem).
>
> ---
>
> **The Problem:**
>
> After the reboot the server was stuck on the start-up splash screen
>   stating “Updating your system 8%”. I tried the following
>
> - Waiting several hours
> - Rebooting
> - Rebooting in Safe Mode (press F8    immediately as the server boots to access this boot option)
> - Rebooting    using Last Known Good Configuration (press F8 immediately as the    server boots to access this boot option)
>
> None of the above worked.
>
> ---
>
> **The Solution:**
>
> - Reboot the server, press F8 to access advanced boot options
> - Select the Option "Repair Your Computer"
> - In the Options screen select **Troubleshoot > Command Prompt**
> - The server boots into a limited command prompt at the **X drive**.
> - Get a list of all the available drives, type “**wmic logicaldisk get name**“. This is important as whilst in the repair environment the
>     drive mappings often get changed around i.e. I was panicking when I
>     changed to the C drive only to find it was empty. In fact the system
>     drive was mapped to the E drive. There’s no obvious way to tell, you
>     just have to change to each drive mapping a run a Dir command. (To
>     know for sure, you can cd to every drive listed above and check if
>     that has Windows related directory. )
> - Navigate to the \Windows\Winsxs folder. Once here you need to find all the files called pending.xml* and rename them all by
>     adding .OLD to the end of the file name. (In my server I had two
>     pending.xml and pending.xml.random_number – I added .OLD to the end of
>     both of these). The reason for this is it’s in one of these there is a
>     corruption that’s the cause of the problem.  **ren pending.xml
>     pending.xml.old**
>
>   - If you have a lot of files with the name and a sequence of numbers, you can use the following from the commandline: **for /r %i
>       in (pending.xml*) do move %i %i.old**
> - Create a new blank pending.xml file in the \Windows\Winsxs folder; **echo > pending.xml**
> - Next up is to run a DISM command to remove/revert all pending actions from the image, in our case these updates attempting to
>     install. However before doing so you must create a scratch folder for
>     the temporary files to be stored in. If you don’t complete this step
>     you will get a **3017 error**, which complains the default temporary
>     location for the scratch folder is too small. Create the scratch
>     folder in the \Windows directory; **mkdir \windows\scratch**
> - Run the following command (NB my system drive was mapped to the E drive);    **DISM /Image:E:\ /Cleanup-Image /RevertPendingActions
>     /scratchdir:E:\Windows\Scratch**
> - Once complete rename the \windows\SoftwareDistribution to SoftwareDistributionOLD; **ren
>     E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistributionOLD**
> - Finally, run **sfc /scannow** – the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files
> - Reboot the server. The start-up splash screen should show spinning dots for a minute or two then boot normally. In my instance it then
>     reported updates couldn’t be installed and so reverted those that had
>     been installed. It then forced another reboot.
> - At this stage the server is ready to have updates installed, but this time only do a few at a time to locate the faulty update.

Comment: This whole post looks like a verbatim copy of https://www.craythorne.co.za/server-2012-stuck-at-updating-your-system-8/ from January 2017.  Are you the author of that blog post?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F8</kbd> command prompt

and then

```
wmic logicaldisk get name
```

and then

```
dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
```

worked for me. In my case the image in question was "`D:`".

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me too. My server was hanging after restart at 7%.
F8 command prompt
and then
wmic logicaldisk get name
and then
dism.exe /image:D:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions
as in my case the image in question was "D:".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well.  I was stuck at 7%.

I did get an error 14098 with the DISM command, and it turned out to be from the pending.xml file created with the ECHO command.  I went ahead and deleted that file, and DISM completed successfully along with all of the other steps.

Thanks!